# SurfaceLayer is now deprecated, how to avoid using it?

Tags: java, gwt, playn

I'm new to PlayN, now I'm trying to draw an image. Seems that examples on the official page (https://developers.google.com/playn/devguide/rendering) were not updated for a long time, they simply don't work with the latest version of PlayN.

I have global <kbd>CanvasImage circle</kbd> and <kbd>SurfaceLayer surf</kbd>. In my init() I have this code:

```java
Graphics g = PlayN.graphics();
surf = g.createSurfaceLayer(g.width(), g.height());
g.rootLayer().add(surf);
```

And this in paint():

```java
surf.surface().clear();
surf.surface().drawImage(circle, 0, 0);
```

The compiler warns that createSurfaceLayer() method is deprecated and offers to use createSurface() and createImageLayer() methods instead. How do I use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed <kbd>SurfaceLayer surf</kbd> to <kbd>ImageLayer imglay</kbd>, removed all the code from paint() and replaced code in init() to this:

```java
imglay = g.createImageLayer();
imglay.setImage(circle);
g.rootLayer().add(imglay);
```

It works, but is it how it should be done?

Comment: If you're just trying to render an image, such as one you've loaded from assets, use an ImageLayer. Your code looks fine for most things you'd want to do.